# Put RShiny app in docker for Windows based local computers

Tags: r, windows, docker, rshiny

I have an RShiny based application developed on Windows 10 using R (4.0.4), RStudio and RShiny. I want to share this application with my colleagues (who also use Windows 10) for them to use but they don't have R or RStudio installed. I want them to be able to use this app without installing R and RStudio since we don't have admin rights on our laptops and getting them requires raising tickets. One possible option would be to host the app on a server and use shiny-server, then share the link to the app. But we don't have a server budget currently.

My primary question is, if there is a way to share the app with my colleagues without them having to go through the hassle of installing R and RStudio.

From my preliminary research, I have found that Dockers (or Rockers by RStudio Inc.) can be used to achieve this by making the app into a "docker image" (whatever this means!). But all the articles I found were about dockerising the RShiny app for Linux based systems and servers. Hence, my secondary question is, if anybody knows this Docker/Rocker can be used on Windows based systems to help me in my scenario explained in first paragraph.

Comment: You can't install docker on your colleagues' machines without root/admin access, so this isn't going to work either.

Comment: Aah okay, thanks for the input.

Comment: There's a way to deploy RShiny apps using `ShinyProxy` on Windows 10 and then deploy on local machine or Amazon EC2 instance.

Here are a few links which can help you out:
 - https://www.databentobox.com/2019/11/05/deploy-r-app-with-shinyproxy/
 - https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/11/deploying-r-shiny-apps-using-shinyproxy-on-windows-10/
 - https://lukesingham.com/shiny-containers-with-shinyproxy/

Some Video Tutorials to complement the learning:
 - https://youtu.be/aoIlaOYRpQs
 - https://youtu.be/bJG04j2B4VI
 - https://youtu.be/hCPheJfoy6c

Edit, Converting the post to comment @SoftwareEngineer